# Api Response as a List / fetching all the data from api response

Tags: list, api, asp.net-core

I am new to .netcore mvc architecture. I am trying to consume the api data response, So far I have successfully fetched the data, but the problem I am facing is when the api response/result is more than one. Forexample if the actuall api response is the following

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"title:\"A\""}},
  "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "date":"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "tstamp":"2019-11-22T12:22:31.698Z",
        "digest":"e23d679991d80d832504e7395d139fe4",
        "contentLength":"25476",
        "boost":0.0,

       "title":["emb- A1]
        "url":"https://www.example.com/a/b/c0/"},
{
        "date":"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "tstamp":"2019-11-22T12:22:31.698Z",
        "digest":"e23d679991d80d832504e7395d139fe4",
        "contentLength":"25476",
        "boost":0.0,
   "title":["emb - A2]
        "url":"https://www.example.com/a/b/c1/"
},
{
        "date":"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "tstamp":"2019-11-22T12:22:31.698Z",
        "digest":"e23d679991d80d832504e7395d139fe4",
        "contentLength":"25476",
        "boost":0.0,
   "title":["emb - A3]
        "url":"https://www.example.com/a/b/c2/"
}
```

I am only getting

```
{"title":"[\r\n  \"emb- A1","source":"https://www.example.com/a/b/c0/"}
```

instead of having all the response data.

My Code is below. 
**Model**
*SearchModel.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace searchEngineTesting.Models
{
    public class SearchModel
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Source;

    }
}
```

**Controller**
*EngineController.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using searchEngineTesting.Models;

namespace searchEngineTesting.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EngineController : ControllerBase {


        [HttpGet("[action]/{query}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Product(string query)
        {
            var model = new SearchModel();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080");
                    var response = await client.GetAsync($"/abc/xxx/select?q=title%3A%22{query}%22");
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var root = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringResult);
                    //var details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchModel>(stringResult);
                    var items = root.SelectToken("").Children().OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);

                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        if (item.Key == "response")
                        {
                            var key = item.Value.SelectToken("").OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);

                            foreach (var k in key)
                            {
                                if(k.Key == "docs")
                                {
                                    var tests = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(k.Value.ToString());
                                    var data = k.Value.SelectToken("").Children().First();
                                    var test = data.SelectToken("").Children().OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value).ToList();
                                    foreach (var t in test)
                                    {
                                        if (t.Key =="url")
                                        {
                                            model.Source = t.Value.ToString();
                                        }
                                        else if (t.Key == "title")
                                        {
                                            model.Title = t.Value.ToString();                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return new JsonResult(model);

                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException httpreq) {
                    return BadRequest("Sorry: There are no results for your query");
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

How can I retrieve whole of the response I am getting from actual API.

Please help..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I retrieve whole of the response I am getting from actual API.

If you want to return all the actual api response,then just use below code:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{query}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Product(string query)
    {
        var model = new SearchModel();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080");
                var response = await client.GetAsync($"/abc/xxx/select?q=title%3A%22{query}%22");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var root = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringResult);

                return new JsonResult(root);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException httpreq)
            {

            }
        }
        return Ok()
     }
```

If you would like to just return `List<SearchModel>` from the actual response,you should not use `var data = k.Value.SelectToken("").Children().First();` which will only retrieve the first element of `docs` array.

Try to foreach `k.Value.SelectToken("").Children()` and return `List<SearchModel>` instead of a `SearchModel`,refer to

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{query}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Product(string query)
    {
        //initialize a list SearchModel
        var modelList = new List<SearchModel>();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080");
                var response = await client.GetAsync($"/abc/xxx/select?q=title%3A%22{query}%22");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var root = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringResult);

                var items = root.SelectToken("").Children().OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    if (item.Key == "response")
                    {
                        var key = item.Value.SelectToken("").OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);

                        foreach (var k in key)
                        {
                            if (k.Key == "docs")
                            {
                                //remove .First()
                                var arrayData = k.Value.SelectToken("").Children();
                                foreach(var data in arrayData)
                                {
                                    var model = new SearchModel();
                                    var test = data.SelectToken("").Children().OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value).ToList();
                                    foreach (var t in test)
                                    {
                                        if (t.Key == "url")
                                        {
                                            model.Source = t.Value.ToString();
                                        }
                                        else if (t.Key == "title")
                                        {
                                            model.Title = t.Value.ToString();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    modelList.Add(model);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return new JsonResult(modelList);

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException httpreq)
            {

            }
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not a list, but only a single object which you would overwrite continuously in your loop so that only one element remains.
Then you will need to iterate over all docs, not just use the first (e.g. `k.Value.SelectToken("").Children().First()`).

So you should be able to resolve your issue by changing your model to a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netstandard-2.1) of `SearchModels`, and ensuring to iterate through all documents (it helps to inspect the variables in a debugger to see what happens).

An easier approach would be using [JsonConvert](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm), where you just would need to mirror the relevant structure of the JSON using C# classes, e.g.:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Title;
    public string Url;
}

public class Result
{
    public Response response;
}

public class Response
{
    public List<Document> docs;
}
```

then deserialize the json simple as:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(stringResult);
```

and finally converting the result to your `SearchModel`:

```
var searchModels = result.response.docs.Select(x => new SearchModel {Source = x.Url, Title = x.Title}).ToList();
```